# Solidity: Type is no callable

Tags: solidity

Practicando con Solidity en la versión 0.5.0 tengo los siguientes errores que no comprendo:
`Type is not callable` y `TypeError: Member "four" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in tuple()`

He buceado por la red pero no he encontrado la respuesta aunque parece ser un error muy habitual. 
`
El error sale en la altura de la función setestructura() en la primera inserción:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Variables {

    string public one = "One";
    int public two = -2;
    uint public tree = 3;
    address public myaddress = msg.sender;

    mapping(address => estructura) maping;

    struct estructura {
        uint four;
        uint five;
    }

    function setestructura(uint a, uint b) public {
        maping(msg.sender).four = a;
        maping(msg.sender).five = b;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cambia los paréntesis por corchetes:

```
maping[msg.sender].four = a;
maping[msg.sender].five = b;
```